# jqueryscript.net plugin barcode generator

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

```
function generateBarcode() {

    var value = "101-33X-7104-01 (M3-2016-10-1)";

    var settings = {
        barWidth: 1,
        barHeight: 50,
        moduleSize: 5,
        showHRI: true,
        addQuietZone: true,
        marginHRI: 5,
        bgColor: "#FFFFFF",
        color: "#000000",
        fontSize: 10,
        output: "css",
        posX: 0,
        posY: 0
    };
    $("#div1").html("").show().barcode(value, "code128", settings);
}
<body onload="generateBarcode()">
    <div id="div1"></div>
</body>
```

How do I get the value of the bar-code and assign it to a variable so that i can dynamically change the value later using a loop with a table, instead of creating multiple div which i may or may not use it later

Comment: it's not clear what you are asking. Do you want to read the values into your function from a table, or you do want to have an array of data and create a table using that data?

Comment: the 2nd one i guess, i would like to loop the barcode in a table